# Which driver do I need to install HL-2250DN?

Tags: printing

Brother provides it's drivers [here](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=ch&lang=de&prod=hl2250dn_eu_as&os=128&flang=English).

Which one do I need and what is the exact procedure?

Solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the first one from the list (Driver Install Tool).
There's a step-by-step guide available on the download page.

Comment: "Will you specify the Device URI?" - What is meant with this?

Comment: It says [here](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadhowto.aspx?c=ch&lang=de&prod=hl2250dn_eu_as&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625), that if you connected it via USB you should selcet No and if you access the printer via the netwok you choose Yes and specify the URI (IP address ot the printer).

Comment: It always says: lpadmin: Bad device-uri scheme "usb".

Answer (score 0):

Adding a newer response since I had this same question when setting up Ubuntu 21.10, using the HL-2250DN as a network printer (-> it is not connected directly to my PC via USB, but through Ethernet).

I did not need the custom 32-bit Brother drivers. Instead, I first installed hpijs:

```
sudo apt install printer-driver-hpijs hpijs-ppds
```

Then I let Ubuntu find the printer automatically through Avahi / DNS-SD. Once found, I selected the "Brother HL-2240D Foomatic/hpijs-pcl5e" printer driver (yes, HL-2240D is correct, even though the printer is actually the HL-2250DN). And this works fine.